# ag/the_silver_searcher How to add new custom file type?

Tags: ag

From what I see the list of languages is hardcoded in the [src/lang.c](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/src/lang.c#L7-L146)
Is there a workaround to add some custom languages besides those listed in the C file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile, that's what I did:

```sh
# 1) I uninstalled precompiled(
apt autoremove silversearcher-ag

# 2) cd /tmp && git clone https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher && cd the_silver_searcher

# 3) added some missing languages to the `langs` array - https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/master/src/lang.c#L7-L146

# 4)
./build.sh

# 5)
sudo make install

# 6) Verified new types appeared in the `` output of:
ag --list-file-types
```